# How to convert "10-jan-2022" string to datetime in flutter

Tags: flutter

I am not able to parse "10-jan-2022" string to datetime in flutter, and getting invalid format

Comment: Please show us the code you currently have (please edit your question to add). It's fairly impossible to debug code without being able to see it!

Answer (score 1):

You can try this.

```
import 'package:intl/intl.dart';

void main() {
  final formatter = DateFormat('d-MMM-yyyy');
  DateTime dateTime = formatter.parseUTC("10-Jan-2022");
  print(dateTime);
}
```